# How to access an individual data in a struct array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, struct

I am trying to access individual data entry in a struct array, so I can format the data output it a more "cosmetic way", an while I can print it, I can not format it as I wish because I can not manage to access the individual elements within the array.

Knowing how to do this would also help me to output data separately for each of the groups (witnesses / criminals).

... yes, I challenged myself to learn swift (I am very very very green at this).

```
import Foundation

// MARK: 1: Data model
struct Kriminal: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let crime: String?
    let witness: Bool
    let yearofcrime: Int?
    let id: Int
    
}

let kriminalArray = [
   Kriminal(name: "Vladimir", surname: "Putin", crime: "Genocide", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2022, id: 098),
    Kriminal(name: "Victor", surname: "Orban", crime: "Corruption", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2021, id: 108),
    Kriminal(name: "Joseph", surname: "Stalin", crime: "Genocide", witness: false, yearofcrime: 1937, id: 048),
    Kriminal(name: "Pol", surname: "Pot", crime: "Genocide", witness: false, yearofcrime: 1975, id: 078),
    Kriminal(name: "Donald", surname: "Trump", crime: "Lying", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2022, id: 298),
   Kriminal(name: "Donald", surname: "Tusk", crime: "Corruption", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2017, id: 038),
   Kriminal(name: "Carla", surname: "Del Ponte", crime: nil, witness: true, yearofcrime: 1982, id: 018)
]

// MARK: 1.1: Sort the data (personal challenge)

let groupTheWitness = Dictionary(grouping: kriminalArray) { $0.witness } // sorting the witnes out from the criminals (optional test)

// MARK: 2: function to display the individual data of a single Kriminal
func tellall(){ // here is code to display individual data of the elements in teh array
    for people in kriminalArray{
        print("\(people)")
    }//placeholder

          
  //  print("Sorted Date: \(obj.date) with title: \(obj.title)")
}
// MARK: 3: for each Kriminal, show the data, ignore if witness = true
func showKriminals(){
    for witness = false in kriminalArray{
   tellall()
    }

showKriminals()
 



print("I am done")
```

Thank you for your suggestions and help.

Comment: If you want to control the output of `print` then have `Kriminal` conform to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement the output you want using the `description` property.

Answer (score 0):

So, as far as I understand from your request, you'd like to filter and sort an array. Instead of going through all array elements, you can use some built-in methods, to keep your code clean and clear.

So you might have something like this:

```swift
struct Criminal: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let crime: String?
    let witness: Bool
    let yearofcrime: Int?
    let id: Int
    
}

let criminalArray = [
   Criminal(name: "Vladimir", surname: "Putin", crime: "Genocide", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2022, id: 098),
   Criminal(name: "Victor", surname: "Orban", crime: "Corruption", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2021, id: 108),
   Criminal(name: "Joseph", surname: "Stalin", crime: "Genocide", witness: false, yearofcrime: 1937, id: 048),
   Criminal(name: "Pol", surname: "Pot", crime: "Genocide", witness: false, yearofcrime: 1975, id: 078),
   Criminal(name: "Donald", surname: "Trump", crime: "Lying", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2022, id: 298),
   Criminal(name: "Donald", surname: "Tusk", crime: "Corruption", witness: false, yearofcrime: 2017, id: 038),
   Criminal(name: "Carla", surname: "Del Ponte", crime: nil, witness: true, yearofcrime: 1982, id: 018)
]

let sorted = criminalArray.sorted { first, second in
    return first.id > second.id
}

dump(sorted)

let filtered = criminalArray.filter { criminal in
    criminal.witness // same as criminal.witness == true
}

dump(filtered)
```

[This](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) might help you get more info

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. I have been playing around with it to better understand it, Is there any way to not print/display a value if "nil" ?